# Custom view/row in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I've successfully implemented a `RecyclerView` using `GirdLayoutManager` (ordinary implementation, nothing special) but now I'm stuck because I want to add a custom view/row after the first 3 elements.
See image below (blue area):

[image]

How can I achieve that? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: check this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your grid layout manager like below:

```
final GridLayoutManager mng_layout = new GridLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), 2);

mng_layout.setSpanSizeLookup( new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                 switch( recyclerAdapter.getItemViewType(position) ) {
                    case MyRecyclerAdapter.TYPE_SINGLE:
                        return 1;
                    case MyRecyclerAdapter.TYPE_DEFAULT:
                        return 2;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mng_layout);
```

And then update your RecyclerViewAdapter as below:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    if (viewType==TYPE_DEFAULT) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_grid_view_item, parent, false);
        return new DefaultViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType==TYPE_SINGLE){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_grid_view_header, parent, false);
        return new SingleItemViewHolder(view);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("There is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
}

 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     return (list.get(position).getType()==TYPE_DEFAULT) ? TYPE_DEFAULT : TYPE_SINGLE;
 }
```

Comment: Happy to help you. Please accept it as correct Answer. Tick the icon below the vote arrows.